# Java output reply so slow

Tags: java

i'm doing a exercise about a snail that climb a wall and i have to calculate  how manys days it would take to reach the top, i already did my algorithm and it give me the expected output but it takes so  long in a input case, basically what code have to do is given N M T   N=how manys meter he climb a day M= how manys meters he fall in the  night and T= what's the lenght of the wall this is my code any help will be useful  this is my code PD it already work but it's too slow

```
       int distance=0;

       int[] up = { 2, 5 ,100};
       int[] down= { 1,1 ,99};
       int[] Top = {5,6 ,1000000000};
       int days = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < up.length; )
       {
           distance += up[i];
           if (Top[i] <= distance)
           {
               days++;
               System.out.println(days);
                i++;
               days = 0;
               distance = 0;

           }
           else
           {
               distance -= down[i];
               days++;
           }

       }
```

the output are the next : case 1: 4
case 2: 2
case 3 :999999901

Comment: how much time it is taking to complete ?

Comment: the two first output is done instaly but the third but takes like 4 seconds and the problem say it gotta be 1 seconds

Comment: unrelated remark: your code would be much clearer if you had used two nested loops, one counting the test cases, the other counting the days.

Comment: Define "too slow"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code can be refactored to simplify it. This is how [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) describes refactoring:

> Code refactoring is the process of restructuring existing computer code—changing the *factoring*—**without changing its external behavior**. Refactoring improves *nonfunctional* attributes of the software. **Advantages include improved code readability and reduced complexity**; these can improve source-code maintainability and create a more expressive internal architecture or object model to improve extensibility. **Typically, refactoring applies a series of standardised basic *micro-refactorings***, each of which is (usually) a tiny change in a computer program's source code that either preserves the behaviour of the software, or at least does not modify its conformance to functional requirements.

So we're going to apply a set of micro-refactorings.

First, the two statements inside the `else` clause can be flipped.

```
} else {
    days++;   // Statement moved up
    distance -= down[i];
}
```

When you do that, both the `if` block and the `else` block starts with `days++;`, so it can be moved outside.

```
for (int i = 0; i < up.length;) {
    distance += up[i];
    days++;   // Statement moved outside
    if (Top[i] <= distance) {
        System.out.println(days);
        i++;
        days = 0;
        distance = 0;
    } else {
        distance -= down[i];
    }
}
```

Since the `for` loop doesn't modify `i`, it behaves like a forever-loop, as long as code inside the loop doesn't change `i`. So, we can add a forever-loop and break out of it when we change `i`. The effect is that nothing has changed, but it prepares for the next set of refactorings.

```
for (int i = 0; i < up.length;) {
    for (;;) {   // Forever-loop
        distance += up[i];
        days++;
        if (Top[i] <= distance) {
            System.out.println(days);
            i++;
            days = 0;
            distance = 0;
            break;   // Break out, since we changed i
        } else {
            distance -= down[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Since the `break` statement is the only way to exit the forever-loop, we can move the code that is before the `break` to outside (i.e. after) the loop.

```
int distance = 0;
int days = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < up.length;) {
    for (;;) {
        distance += up[i];
        days++;
        if (Top[i] <= distance) {
            break;
        } else {
            distance -= down[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(days);   // Moved outside forever-loop
    i++;                        // Moved outside forever-loop
    days = 0;                   // Moved outside forever-loop
    distance = 0;               // Moved outside forever-loop
}
```

Since `days` and `distance` are initialized to `0` before the outer loop, and reinitialized to `0` at the end of the loop, we can just do that at the start of the loop instead, and we can then declare them there. We can also move the `i++` to the `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < up.length; i++) {   // i++ moved here
    int distance = 0;   // Moved to top of loop and declared here
    int days = 0;       // Moved to top of loop and declared here
    for (;;) {
        distance += up[i];
        days++;
        if (Top[i] <= distance) {
            break;
        } else {
            distance -= down[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(days);
}
```

We will now do the opposite operation for the two statements that increment `distance` and `days` inside the forever-loop, i.e. do those two statement both before the loop, and at the end of the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < up.length; i++) {
    int distance = 0;
    int days = 0;
    distance += up[i];   // Moved here
    days++;              // Moved here
    for (;;) {
        if (Top[i] <= distance) {
            break;
        } else {
            distance -= down[i];
        }
        distance += up[i];   // Also moved here
        days++;              // Also moved here
    }
    System.out.println(days);
}
```

The initialization of `distance` and `days` can be combined with the incrementing done before the forever-loop. Also, since the `break` exits the loop, there is no need for `else` anymore.

```
for (int i = 0; i < up.length; i++) {
    int distance = up[i];   // Combined =0 with +=up[i]
    int days = 1;           // Combined =0 with ++
    for (;;) {
        if (Top[i] <= distance)
            break;
        distance -= down[i];   // else clause eliminated
        distance += up[i];
        days++;
    }
    System.out.println(days);
}
```

`distance` is only used inside the forever loop, so we can move the declaration to the loop. The update of `distance` can be moved to the 3rd part of the forever loop. The `if` statement is at the top of the forever-loop, so it can become the loop condition instead, changing the forever-loop to a regular `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < up.length; i++) {
    int days = 1;
    for (int distance = up[i]; distance < Top[i]; distance += up[i] - down[i]) {
        days++;
    }
    System.out.println(days);
}
```

See how much simpler your code is now, and we never changed the logic of the code. We just moved it around, i.e. *refactored it*.

Your performance issue is caused by the inner loop having to iterate almost a billion times for the 3rd use-case, but now that we can see a simple `for` loop, we can actually *calculate* how many times it will iterate.

To build that formula, consider a normal loop.

```
for (int value = start; value < stop; value += step)
```

How many times will that iterate? It will have to add `step` a total of `x` times until `value` reaches `stop`, so that means `x = (stop - start) / step`.

If `stop - start` is not an exact multiple of `step`, we need to make sure we always round up, so `value` will be `>= stop`. Using integer math, you do that by adding `step - 1` before dividing, since integer division will truncate the result, leading to this formula: `x = (stop - start + step - 1) / step`

Applying that to our loop, we get:

```
x = (stop - start + step - 1) / step
x = (Top[i] - up[i] + (up[i] - down[i]) - 1) / (up[i] - down[i])
x = (Top[i] - down[i] - 1) / (up[i] - down[i])

days = 1 + x
days = 1 + (Top[i] - down[i] - 1) / (up[i] - down[i])
```

Since there is no need to assign result to a variable `days` anymore, your code becomes:

```
int[] up = { 2, 5, 100 };
int[] down = { 1, 1, 99 };
int[] Top = { 5, 6, 1000000000 };
for (int i = 0; i < up.length; i++)
    System.out.println(1 + (Top[i] - down[i] - 1) / (up[i] - down[i]));
```

*Output*

```
4
2
999999901
```

Result is instantly calculated. No delays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little maths to come up with a closed formula:

```
Math.ceil(((double)top - down) / (up - down))
```